# Powershell won't run ps1 files

Tags: windows-10, powershell

Completely baffled by this.  Can't seem to run any ps1 files on powershell??  I know for sure it was working fine last week.

Here is the error I'm getting.  It suggests the file doesn't exist, so I proved it does by using Test-Path first...

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cd C:\Users\Public
if (Test-Path test.ps1) {
    ./test.ps1
}
./test.ps1 : The term './test.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:3 char:5
+     ./test.ps1
+     ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (./test.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any suggestions of what I could try?

Doesn't seem to be related to permissions.  I was originally running from a network drive, but same result from C drive.  Restarted the PC 2 times already.  I'm not aware of any changes made to my PC in the last week that could have caused this?

EDIT
As requested:

```
PS C:\Users\Public> dir .\test.ps1


    Directory C:\Users\Public


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       01/11/2019     14:35            208 test.ps1
```

Comment: Have you tried changing hte forward slash to a back-slash? `.\test.ps1`

Comment: @Keith Yes, tried both ways.  Tried with double quotes, single quotes, full path, etc.

Comment: test.ps1 is in the Users/Public folder? Make _dir .\test.ps1_

Comment: @YisroelTech result of dir added to question.  Thanks

Comment: Try gc ./test.ps1

Comment: @WalterMitty - gc successfully prints the contents of the file

Comment: @WalterMitty in the _dir_ results your current directory is **Users\Public** while in the first results the current directory is **WINDOWS\system32**

Comment: Curious if you open CMD and run `powershell -noexit "& ""C:\Users\Public\test.ps1"""` does it work?

Comment: @Narzard sadly not.  Same error.  But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Skytunnel I am almost wondering the public folder has execution limitations. Move to test.ps1 to c:\temp and try to run it from there

Comment: @Narzard it's a work computer, where IT have locked down access to the C drive.  The public folder is just one they've missed I guess.  I don't keep the script there, I run it on a network drive.  But moved to C drive for testing why it's not working.  It doesn't work anywhere, and it's the same for every script

Comment: Has IT implemented some sort of filter that prevents PS from seeing the file when it goes to execute it?  Your previous responses indicate that PS can open the file.

Comment: What is the execution policy on the computer?

Comment: @WalterMitty I have had other colleagues test it without problem so I don't believe IT would have implemented anything like that.  And I had set my execution policy to unrestriced for the CurrentUser, it was working under that fine last week.

Comment: have you confirmed that there are NO extra, non-printing characters involved? i cannot think of any other way to get the problem you show. what happens with >>> `(Get-ChildItem -Path .\test.ps1).Name | Format-Hex` <<< do you see any unexpected chars showing in that listing?

Comment: @Walter Thanks everyone for all the suggestions.  Scripts are now working again.  I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a satisfactory answer as to why the following caused it; but scripts are now working again.  So here's what happened...

I've been working remotely from home the last 2 weeks using CAG (Critix Access Gateway).

I went back in the office today for the first time, and when I connected directly to the network, all my scripts where working again as normal.

It turns out IT have been releasing an alternative to CAG use called CheckPointVPN.  My user group was updated to support it earlier in the week (which may have been when my scripts stopped working?).

I got it fully installed while in the office, and now I'm back working remotely from home again, and all scripts are working well.

As I said, this isn't exactly a clear answer.  But maybe it'll help someone else who might be experenicing something similar

Comment: It's more of an answer then you realize.  The error you received basically indicated the script could not find the file.

Comment: @Ramhound what's that got to do with working remotely though?  Especialy when you consider that I tested it from the C Drive?

Comment: You indicated that it was solved once you had a working secure connection to your work's network.  The script not being found is literally the only explanation for the error, if you made no other changes to the script, between when it wasn't working and it was working.  The file that could not be found, likely is within the script you called, not the script you were running directly.